# Running ARM CUDA software on Docker from x86 machine

Tags: docker, cuda, nvidia, nvidia-jetson-nano

Here's my situation: I have an x86 machine that I need to create a Docker image that is compatible with Jetson Nano. I don't have the Jetson nano but I want to test whether or not my Docker image works properly and I need to test a few pieces of code that run a CUDA binary. So I set up my nano docker image `nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-pytorch:r32.4.4-pth1.6-py3` and ran it on my x86 machine. Then I entered the container in interactive mode and started a python interpreter. Then I tried to import PyTorch

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import torch
```

And it failed. My output was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 188, in <module>
    _load_global_deps()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 141, in _load_global_deps
    ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libcurand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My docker image matches the CUDA binaries I should have installed on my host machine. I need to get my code to run but I'm not sure why I continue to have CUDA binary problems even when I'm using an NVIDIA sanctioned docker image. The CUDA binaries should be pre-loaded on the image.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem here with the current image: `nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-pytorch:r32.4.4-pth1.6-py3` is that accessing the NVIDIA driver on a host x86 machine isn't supported. If you go to the official nvidia-docker github you will see a section for [building jetson docker containers on an x86 machine](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/NVIDIA-Container-Runtime-on-Jetson#building-jetson-containers-on-an-x86-workstation-using-qemu). Then notice right at the bottom it says

> Known limitation: Unfortunately you won’t be able to run any binary
> that calls into the NVIDIA driver on the x86 host.

Meaning the task of verifying any code that calls into an NVIDIA binary is impossible. Only route is to create the best possible container that you can, and then verify that the code works properly on a physical Jetson device.